# How to open standard browser from Facebook in-App browser and preload an url?

Tags: javascript, facebook-browser

When user press a button and useragent is detected it is Facebook In-App borswer, I would open a standard browser and open an url. Is it a way to do it?

Tried this, this not work

```
window.parent.location.assign('https://tikex-dev.com/')
```

```js
onClick={() => {
    if (isFacebookApp()) {
        //  window.parent.location.assign('https://tikex-dev.com/')
        alert('to upload, press here')
    }
}}
```